# 405 - HTTP verb used to access this page is not allowed. Error

Tags: asp.net, jsp

I am very new to Asp.net . the contact of my site is not working .when i submit a data i am getting

> 405 - HTTP verb used to access this page is not allowed.
>   The page you are looking for cannot be displayed because an invalid method (HTTP verb) was used to attempt access.

i have tried so many on-line solution (changing fine name etc) , but doesn't helps me much

Here is my code

**about.htm**

```
<frame src="about-main.htm" scrolling="yes" name="mainFrame" >
```

**about-main.htm**

```
<form name="quotation request" method="post" action="send-mail.jsp">
   //form data
 <input name="Submit" type="submit" class="btn"  onClick="MM_validateForm('name','','R','phone','','R','email','','RisEmail');return document.MM_returnValue" value="Send Email">
```

**send-mail.jsp**

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Rio Marketing & Promotions - Custom Merchandise</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
    <link href="rio_page_style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
    <!-- 
    if (top == self) self.location.href = "quote.htm";
    // -->
    </SCRIPT>
    <script src="javascript.js"></script>
    <style>
    .btn {
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, san-serif;
    font-size: 10pt;
    margin-left: 45px;
    background-color: #036;
    }
    .formfields {
    text-align: left;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, san-serif;
    font-size: 10pt;
    color: #000;
    padding: 0px;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <table width="758" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
      <tr>
     <td><div id="content">
      <table width="650" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
     <tr> 
    <td colspan="2"><table width="650" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
     <tr> 
       <td><h1>EMAIL RIO MARKETING & PROMOTIONS</h1></td>
       <td><div align="right"><img src="images/credcards.gif">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</div></td>
     </tr>
      </table></td>
     </tr>
     <tr> 
    <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
     </tr>
      <tr> 
    <td width="95" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="581"><div class="mainimage"><%
    ' Create the JMail message Object
    set msg = Server.CreateOBject( "JMail.Message" )

    ' Set logging to true to ease any potential debugging
    ' And set silent to true as we wish to handle our errors ourself
    msg.Logging = true
    msg.silent = true

    ' Most mailservers require a valid email address
    ' for the sender
    msg.From = Request.Form("email")    
    msg.FromName = Request.Form("name")

    ' Note that as addRecipient is method and not
    ' a property, we do not use an equals ( = ) sign
    msg.AddRecipient "mail@domain.com", "Peter Allen"


    ' The subject of the message
    msg.Subject = "Rio Website Information Request"
    'add every form element and its value to the email
    msg.Body = ""
    ' we use HTMLBody and appendHTML
    msg.HTMLBody = "<html><body>"
    msg.appendHTML "<b>Name: </b>"
    msg.appendHTML Request.form("name") & "<br>"
    msg.appendHTML "<b>Email: </b>"
    msg.appendHTML Request.form("email") & "<br>"
    msg.appendHTML "<b>Company: </b>"
    msg.appendHTML Request.form("company") & "<br>"
    If Request.form("phone") <> "" then
    msg.appendHTML "<b>Phone: </b>"
    msg.appendHTML Request.form("phone") & "<br>"
    End If
    msg.appendHTML "<b>Heard From: </b>"
    msg.appendHTML Request.form("hearabout") & "<br>"
    msg.appendHTML "<b>Description of items: </b>"
    msg.appendHTML Request.form("description") & "<br>"
    msg.appendHTML "<b>Quantity: </b>"
    msg.appendHTML Request.form("quantity") & "<br>"
    If Request.form("production") <> "" then
    msg.appendHTML "<b>Production Due By: </b>"
    msg.appendHTML Request.form("production") & "<br>"
    End If
    msg.appendHTML "<b>Comments: </b>"
    msg.appendHTML Request.form("comments") & "<BR><br>"
    ' Now send the message, using the indicated mailserver
    if not msg.Send("mail.apexhost.com.au" ) then
     Response.write "<pre>" & "Email Failure" & "</pre>"
    else
     Response.write "<p>&nbsp;</p><p class='orangetext' align='center'>Your email has been sent!</p>" 
     Response.write "<p class='smalltext' align='center'>Thank you for your request. We will contact you shortly.</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p>"
    end if

    ' And we're done! the message has been sent.

    %>     </div></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
    <td valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
     </tr>
      </table><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
    </div></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

And my **web.config** file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <configuration>
         <system.webServer>
            <directoryBrowse enabled="false" />
            <defaultDocument>
            <files>
            <clear />
            <add value="Default.htm" />
            <add value="Default.asp" />
            <add value="index.htm" />
            <add value="index.html" />
            <add value="iisstart.htm" />
            <add value="default.aspx" />
            <add value="index.php" />
        </files>
    </defaultDocument>
    <httpErrors errorMode="DetailedLocalOnly" existingResponse="Auto" />
    </system.webServer>
  </configuration>
```

You can test this site also [contact-page](http://riomarketing.com.au/about.htm)

any help regarding this ? i have missed out any thing? or need to add some thing in web.config file ?

Comment: When you submit, you POST, you need to configure your server-side action to allow a POST.

Comment: Are you using post or get?  please show how you send data and current controller

Comment: Using POST method

Comment: can you share you controller code ? cannot help you without seeing the code